Unreal 5.4's skeletal mesh shading problem
Hello wise guys of the Internet. I encountered a shading issue in my project.
It seems like, there are additional shadows of a character that were cut by a rectangle or smth, and they appear when character moves at a certain angle to camera(like 45 or 135)
Those shadows
I assume the problem is in my mesh or my skeleton (I use a custom one(somehow without a "root" bone, if that is important)) or in material (this is less likely, mats consist only color maps,but maybe). When I rotate camera, the shadows disappear. The cloth simulation doesn't work as well.
Send help

from the unreal-engine5 tag: For non-programming related questions, use https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/.

https://dev.epicgames.com/documentation/en-us/unreal-engine/visibility-and-occlusion-culling-in-unreal-engine
After an instant insight and 2 mins of searching the problem has been solved
In your blueprint class - problem mesh - rendering - Bounding box is set to 1.
Increase it until you're done.
enter image description here
maybe i should delete the question

"maybe i should delete the question..." I agree.
